# Dataset with personal information (eg. gender, age) and movie preferences

Tags: data-request, music, film

Does anyone know of a data set that contains anonymous but personal information about people connected to their movie preferences or alternatively some other preferences (i.e. favorite music, etc)?

Comment: You should search "survey results" with keywords like "favorite movie". [Here is an example](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-39rV9Y_SAhVFPBoKHZv8AfMQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.its.ohiou.edu%2Fmediamessage%2FGinaManninosurveydata6FINAL1.xls&usg=AFQjCNHSOQeffGCD54SiBt9Ju1X4O1Tjqg&sig2=fbf3RBYsxwoHQ8xfONjxQQ) of result on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Netflix Challenge dataset](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Netflix+Challenge+dataset).
Netflix wanted to find a better recommendation algorithm, so it will certainly contain what you're looking for.